# How to set current directory to a file's location through a foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to find a way to set my current working directory to a parent folder of a file so that I can copy a PDF that lives in a folder above a particular folder.

Basically what I am trying to do is this;
Check which folders on a share have been modified in the last day
Recursively search through those modified folders for a clxml file that contains a word I need
Set my current location to that path, browse back a folder and copy out any PDF's to a new location.

So far I have everything working except I can't figure out how to set my current directory to the location of the clxml within the foreach loop. I can't figure out what needs to go between the final `Get-ChildItem` and my `copy-item`

```
$ClxmlFolder = Get-ChildItem "\\clwsdrapsi02\BATCH STORAGE\" -Directory| Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge ((Get-Date).Date) -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt ((Get-Date).Date).AddDays(+1)}

$ClxmlPath = Get-ChildItem $ClxmlFolder.FullName -Recurse -Directory -Include 'clxml' | Select-Object -Property FullName, Directory

foreach ($Folder in $ClxmlPath)
{
  $ClxmlPath.FullName
  break
}

foreach ($File in $ClxmlPath)
{
  $ClxmlFile = Get-ChildItem $ClxmlPath.FullName -Recurse -Filter "*.clxml" | Where-Object {Select-String Newton $_ -Quiet} | Select-Object -Property Fullname, Directory
  $ClxmlFile.Fullname
  Copy-Item .\*.PDF -destination "C:\test uploads\Uploaded" -Recurse -Force
  Break
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `Select-Object -Property Fullname, Directory` you're converting a [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) object into a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) which in this case, you do not want. We can get the parent folder of a file (a `FileInfo` object) by calling it's [`.Directory` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.directory?view=net-6.0#system-io-fileinfo-directory) and furthermore, this would return a [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0) object which has a [`.Parent` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.parent?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-parent).

Summarizing, first you can do your filtering:

```
$ClxmlFile = Get-ChildItem $ClxmlPath.FullName -Recurse -Filter "*.clxml" |
    Where-Object { Select-String Newton $_ -Quiet }
```

And then, assuming this only returns **one file**, you can either `Set-Location` or if you want to change directory to the parent folder and then go back, you can use `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`.

```
if($ClxmlFile) { # if the above filtering returned a result
    Set-Location $ClxmlFile.Directory
    # rest of the logic here
}
```

If you want to change directory to the parent's parent directory:

```
Set-Location $ClxmlFile.Directory.Parent
```

Alternatively, instead of changing your current directory, you could simple combine the `FullName` of the Parent folder with `\*.PDF`:

```
$source = $ClxmlFile.Directory.FullName + '\*.PDF'
Copy-Item $source -Destination "C:\test uploads\Uploaded" -Recurse -Force
```